# Avoiding Incredibuild error when building

Tags: unreal-4, build-process

Apparently the UE4 Installed Build script function is trying to use Incredibuild, but halting with an error.

I believe this is due to my Agent Services not running, due to the fact that I have none.

I don't have a license, and so I can't use Incredibuild.

How can I modify the scripts to not use Incredibuild?
I downloaded FastBuild, and want to give that a try. 
I just need help in knowing which scripts to modify.

Comment: Can you please show us the full text of the error?

Comment: I noticed the initial error has gone away since I ran the Incredibuild Agent tray icon. So the build got further, but after a long time, it returned another error related to Incredibuild. See here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/39wyyak05et7h4f/build_error.txt?dl=0.I tried the suggestion here https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/engine-source-github/1722114-failed-to-create-installed-build-using-buildgraph-unknown-error but the error does not go away.

Comment: I just noticed from that error AllowXGE="True", so let me try changing to false again. Maybe I did not save the file.

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect the current state of your problem, including the full text of the error you're getting.

Comment: I think you edited it correctly. I found the answer. The build has gotten past the error, so I know which scripts to edit now, and what to edit. I will post it in a minute.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent Incredibuild being used...
For certain, AllowXGE needs to be set to false, in ...\UnrealEngine-4.22\Engine\Source\Programs\AutomationTool\BuildGraph\Tasks\CompileTask.cs

I also set bAllowXGE to false (public bool bAllowXGE = false;), in ...\UnrealEngine-4.22\Engine\Source\Programs\UnrealBuildTool\Configuration\BuildConfiguration.cs, but I am not sure if this was necessary.

I am not sure if setting AllowParallelExecutor = false is necessary, as recommended by [this answer](https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/engine-source-github/1722114-failed-to-create-installed-build-using-buildgraph-unknown-error), since I forgot to set that in CompileTask.cs, and the build went through, anyway.

I get errors with FASTBuild but I will play around with this at some later time, while building projects.